# how to fix the scrollbar always at the bottom of a div?

Tags: jquery, css

I am doing a simple chat application,I want to fix the scrollbar of a div always at the bottom.just like this[image]

When loading the index page the scrollbar must be at the bottom

Here is my style.css

```
body{
font: 0.9em monospace;
}
   .messages{
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    width: 250px;
    height: 210px;
    padding: 10px;
    overflow-y:scroll;

}
.message{
    color: slategrey;

}
 .message p{
    margin: 5px 0;
}
.entry{
   width: 260px;
   height: 40px;
   padding: 5px;
   margin-top: 5px;
   font: 1em fantasy;

}
```

Here is my index.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = (isset($_GET['user']) === TRUE) ? (int) $_GET['user'] : 0;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"></link>
  </head>
   <body>
      <div class="chat">
           <div class="messages" id="messages">
           </div>
        <textarea class="entry" placeholder="type here and press enter"></textarea>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/chat.js"> </script>
</body>
```

How can i set this,please help me..
Thanks

Comment: [This may give you some insight](http://jsfiddle.net/97z6Q/)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try this jquery :

```
$(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
  return false;
```

and here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/EX6vs/

or refers to the height of the element (many agree is the right way), as below:

```
$(".messages").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "slow");
  return false;
```

and here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/69vpnyu1/

Comment: Thank you Fredy! I have see soo many examples, all saying the same thing: scrollTop = scrollHeight. There are two keys here: First, .animate. That is key to actually get it to move. Second, you used $(document).height and not the height of the (".messages"). Which really means you need to take the number of data lines withing your object(div, textarea, etc) and multiple that by the height of the font size, aka, the height of the window within your object. So in a sense, the $document is still wrong, but it was enough to help me figure out why everyone elses was wrong.

Answer (score 8):

you want something like this, where box is the div that contains your chat. call these on page load.

```
var box = document.getElementById('Box');
box.scrollTop = box.scrollHeight;
```

also call this when you post a new chat.

i had created a similar application using google app engine. you can have look at it here

http://chatter-now.appspot.com/

feel free to use it as reference. although you are using php, the visual aspects might be helpful.

Comment: its kind of like a chatroom/guestbook hybrid. whatever you write there sticks.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `jQuery` as you can see the demo here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9S92E/

Answer (score 2):

```
function loadchatval(){
    $.post('loadchat.php',function(data){               
    $('#load_chat').html(data); 
    $("#load_chat").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
    return false;
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below line of code to scroll vertical scrollbar always in bottom of the ***whole page***.

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
```

Below line of code to scroll vertical scrollbar always in bottom of scrollable div container named to "***daViewerContainer***".

```
$("#daViewerContainer").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "fast");
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with:

```
$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
```

All depends how you configure your div's, then use the div for document.
But this one works exellent with sticky footers as well.