# How can i make a div scroll to its end, Y-Axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a div with chat, that is already scroll-able. But i want it to scroll to last chat automatically.
Here is what chat box looks like when load.
[image]

But i want it like image below, when it loads.

[image]

How can i achieve this? Kind help is appreciated, Thank you!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/15629743/4672534

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you try to understand `height` and `scrollheight` values, the formula will be:

```
Element.scrollTop = Element.scrollHeight - Element.offsetHeight;
```

> Note: `Element` variable stands for scroll container element.