# How to fix the vertically scrollbar always at the bottom of a page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have to display a page with style: `overflow-y:scroll` on the body tag.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629599/how-to-fix-the-scrollbar-always-at-the-bottom-of-a-div) but that is only for a `div` tag. I have to apply the style on the page. Please check the accepted answer. Would you help me solve this?

```js
$("body").scrollTop($('body').height())
```

```css
body{ overflow-y:scroll;height:200px;width:200px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages">
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>

     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
     Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    Hello<br>
    <br>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Or you can check this link http://jsfiddle.net/9S92E/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to fix the scrollbar always at the bottom of a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15629599/how-to-fix-the-scrollbar-always-at-the-bottom-of-a-div)

Comment: I already upload that link..that is showing div not body.

Comment: I am talking about browser scroll bar.

Comment: I know, you answered your own question in your question. Please try and apply what is being demonstrated on that page. The answer **is there**! The demo code in the accepted answer will work, you simply need a different selector.

Comment: Right,Demo code is working.But that is creating new scroll bar.

Comment: I added on google chrome new tab image.In that scroll bar is showing at bottom of page.Please check image ....

Comment: An in second image output showing like this

Comment: Checkout this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/9S92E/197/

Comment: Thanks for reply Mr.Aakash.before I tried that code but scroll bar is shoeing on top

Comment: Did it solve your problem?

Comment: No, That scroll bar is showing on top.I need at bottom.

Comment: You checked the fiddle that I shared right?

Comment: Yes,I checked that,But scroll is showing on top not bottom

Comment: Check this codepen link then: http://codepen.io/Sky-123/pen/EgooPB

Comment: @AakashThakur, your JSFiddle had CSS that was limiting the height of the `<body>` element and that's why it wasn't scrolling to the bottom. If you remove the CSS from [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9S92E/200/) it will work as you intended and the Codepen.

Comment: Check the codepen link that I added. @hungerstar